# How to ignore the field that common in two tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables

```
t1                           t2
-------------------         ---------------------
no       course              no        equivalent 
-------------------         ---------------------
1        MATH 101             2         CHEM 111      
2        CHEM 101
3        ENG 101
```

How I can write query or query with function in php language that show me courses and disappear the courses that its no common between the two tables.

likes this

output

```
--------------------
no        course
--------------------
1        MATH 101
3        ENG 101
```

in the output table course number 2 `(  2        CHEM 101)` do not appear in the table because its number shared between t1 and t2 .
I want like that.

Comment: Does the equivalent really `CHEM 111` or `CHEM 101` also?

Comment: @Anant This only works when there is only 1 row in t2. Otherwise you get "2, CHEM 101, 3, other-equivalent"

Comment: Something like `SELECT * FROM t1 NATURAL JOIN t2` will give you the results you want. Is your question also how to execute MySQL queries in PHP? Those are really two separate questions.

Comment: you accepted a wrong answer. Also can you please tell that ids will always same in both table for common values every time? if no then my friend you will not get any help from below these answers

Comment: `what happen if id differs in both table but values are common? then what you want as output`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

`SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE t1.no NOT IN (SELECT no FROM t2)`

Comment: what happen if second table have more numbers of row? your query will not work i think like `SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE t1.no!=(1,2,3,4,5)`

Comment: why comparison based on id , what happen if id differs in both table but values are common?

Answer (score 2):

```
select no From t1 where no not in (select no from t2);
```

Comment: why comparison based on id , what happen if id differs in both table but values are common?

Comment: you just need to change the column name, `select no From t1 where no not in (select ID from t2 );`

Comment: what happen if both table have 100's of ids which are different in both table but values are common?

Comment: there must be something common between the two tables,

Comment: two example :- both tables have 3 columns and no one is similar. second:-  both table have 3 columns but column 1 from t1 is equal to column 3 from t2(in term of value) , also column 3 from t1 is equal to column 1 in t2 and column 2 in both table have different values?]

Comment: on the query i am comparing the ids values. the other columns values are ignored.